# RecyclerView: Using different LayoutManagers and item structure based on screen orientation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working with `recyclerview` that should use different element positioning(grid for landscape and list for portrait) with different `.xml` structure for items.

For the first part I see solution in simple orientation checking in `onCreateView()` method:

```
 switch (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
            case 1:
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                break;
            case 2:
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2));
                break;
        }
```

But for the second part I have doubts. The simplest way is to pass LayoutManager as a constructor parameter to Adapter and check layout in `onCreateViewHolder()` with `instanceof` operator. But it doesn't look as good
  or right solution.

So, are there any common pattern or better way for such situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide different layout resource files depending on screen orientation, you can create resource folders named layout-land (landscape) and layout-port (portrait) and system handles the rest automatically. 
A tipp: You don't need both folders. If your default orientation is portrait then just create the layout-land folder for landscape mode. The layout resource files have to have the same name!

Comment: If I create two different layouts for portrait and landscape the system will choose the one needed automatically. But how can I set the LayoutManager of the Recyclerview? I need it to be different in portrait and different in landscape.

Comment: Try what Autumn_Cat did in the original post. Looks fine

Comment: Amazing! btw... I created the layout folder, but first it did not show up on file strucure menu [refreshed & tried to create folder again, and AS said folder "already exists"], so I had to to go file explorer and manually put .xml file in to that folder. After that the landscape xml showed up.

Comment: @jlively You can set a different layout manager for landscape variant (`layout-land`) using the `app:layoutManager="<your-desired-layout>"` property within the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a folder with the different layouts for each screen size you want to support. See [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) for more details. Pay special attention to the suffixes to specify screen size and orientation.